# Global location of Cloud Shell home directory on Google Cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

Does GCP assign a global location (`gs://...something...`) for the home directory in Cloud Shell? Like buckets are `gs://$BUCKET_NAME/`, where `$BUCKET_NAME` is globally unique.

At the shell prompt, all I can see is:

```
$USERNAME@cloudshell:~ ($PROJECT_ID)
```

Comment: I don't think that home directories in Cloud Shell are in fact buckets. Cloud Shell is a VM with a disk, and the home directory is on that disk. Or maybe I'm not understanding well your question ?

Comment: I agree that the Cloud Shell VM home directory is (apparently) not the same as a bucket which has a global location. I'm just curious to understand "where" the storage in the Cloud Shell home directory is located.

Earlier I tried to transfer a file into Dataprep by trying to specify my Cloud Shell home directory, and realised that this wouldn't work, which got me curious.

Comment: Cloud Shell runs in a container. The home directory is mapped to a Cloud Storage location owned by and managed by Google. You have no access to that storage location outside of Cloud Shell.

Comment: That's great. Makes sense. Thanks @JohnHanley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cloud Shell is globally distributed across multiple Google Cloud Platform regions](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#zone_selection). When you first connect to Cloud Shell, you will be automatically assigned to the closest available geographical region. You cannot pick your own region and in the event that Cloud Shell does not pick the most optimal region, it will try to migrate your Cloud Shell VM to a closer region when it is not in use.

To view your current region, run the following command from a Cloud Shell session:
$ curl metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone

Please note that Cloud Shell provisions 5 GB of free [persistent disk storage](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#persistent_disk_storage) mounted as your $HOME directory on the virtual machine instance. This storage is on a per-user basis and is available across projects. Unlike the instance itself, this storage does not time out on inactivity. All files you store in your home directory, including installed software, scripts and user configuration files like .bashrc and .vimrc, persist between sessions. Your $HOME directory is private to you and cannot be accessed by other users.

Answer (score 0):

No, the cloud shell VM storage is not available as a storage bucket.

But if your intention was to use copy data in and out of the cloud-shell VM storage, you can easily do that

From [doc](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-cloud-shell-with-gcloud-cli) ,

```
gcloud cloud-shell scp cloudshell:~/data.txt localhost:~data.txt
```